# How can I automatically overlap 2 equal objects that are at different locations/scale/rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to take two objects and overlap them 1:1. I have 2 .obj objects in a unity project and the end result I am looking for is a code of how to automatically look for object #1 in object #2 and rearrange object 1 so that it overlaps it 1:1 with object 2. As the title describes, object #1 is at a different scale/rotation/location than object #2.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Transform.localScale, use that and store both of the scale values in vector3
s, store both of their transform positions, then set one equal to anothers.

Comment: IMO, I think you could just look up each action you want to do one by one, and you could solve it, as in, How to change transform position of one object equal to another. How to get the scale of the object, How to get the rotation of an object. Then piece them together.